# Присваиваем личную cms пользователю.

Tags: директива, php, select

Здравствуйте! Собственной сабж, но расскажу подробнее:
у меня есть небольшая cms, хочу сделать так, пользователь регистрируется на сайте, и ему автоматически присвается личная дериктория с этой же cms, но запросы в cms, идут к базе данных каждого пользователя, а к общей бд сайта. Подскажите собственно как, какими функциями пользоваться что-бы, реализовать данный функционал, или может литературу по подобным вещам знаете?

Comment: Пропустили "Не", и пропал смысл вопроса:

> но запросы в cms, идут к базе данных каждого пользователя, а к общей бд сайта

По сути вопроса, посмотрите, как реализован WordPress Multi User.

Answer (score 1):

Неплохим решением былобы изменить CMS, чтобы она могла работать с одной бд для всех юзеров. Например завести поле для каждого пользователя с его ид для каждой таблицы CMS.